# Build excel as in-memory object to be dowloaded

Tags: python, excel, pandas, flask

In python I have a flask server with and endpoint at which users can request for data to be download when they press a button in the template. Until now I returned the data as a csv file:

```
df_results = pd.DataFrame(raw_results)
response = df_results.to_csv()
return response, 200
```

And at the javascript side (csv_as_str is the response param introduced before in the python part):

```
const element = document.createElement('a');
element.setAttribute('href', 'data:text/plain;charset=utf-8,' + encodeURIComponent(csv_as_str));
element.setAttribute('download', filename + ".csv");
element.style.display = 'none';
document.body.appendChild(element);
element.click();
document.body.removeChild(element);
```

This works good but now I would like to return an excel file instead. The problem is that the [to_excel](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_excel.html) method from pandas doesn't return anything like the [to_csv](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_csv.html) method does when path_or_buf == None.

Any idea how this could be achieved?

Thanks.

Comment: I don't believe you can get an excel file as a string. Could you instead create the excel file (on disk) and send that instead?

Comment: I would like to avoid storing the file on disk in order to keep away from future cleaning actions.

Answer (score 0):

Write `pandas.DataFrame` as excel to `io.BytesIO`, for example

```
import io
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'X':[1]})  # simple example
data = io.BytesIO()
with pd.ExcelWriter(data) as writer:
    df.to_excel(writer)
data.seek(0)
```

then use that as `flask.send_file` first argument, i.e.

```
from flask import send_file
return send_file(data,"application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet",as_attachment=True,attachment_filename="filename.xlsx")
```

This should work without JavaScript conhortions, but might need some tweaking.

Disclaimer: I do not have ability to test flask part.

If you are wondering, how I discovered mimetype, then I used [`mimetypes`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/mimetypes.html) built-in module following way

```
import mimetypes
print(mimetypes.guess_type("file.xlsx"))
```